# Efficient cosine similarity computation in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

There are several ways I can compute the cosine similarities between a Spark ML vector to each ML vector in a Spark DataFrame column then sorting for the highest results.  However, I can't come up with a method that is faster than replacing the `/data/` in a Spark ML Word2Vec model, then using `.findSynonyms()`.  The problem is the Word2Vec model is held entirely in the driver which can cause memory issues if the data set I want to compare to gets too big.

1. Is there a more efficient method than the ones I have shown below?
2. Could the data for the Word2Vec model be distributed across the cluster?
3. Could the the `.findSynonyms()` [Scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2Vec.scala#L571toL619) be modified to make a spark sql function that can operate efficiently over a whole Spark DataFrame?

Methods I have tried:

1. rdd function:

```py
# vecIn = vector of same dimensions as 'vectors' column 
def cosSim(row, vecIn):
    return (
        tuple(( Vectors.dense( Vectors.dense(row.vectors.dot(vecIn)) /
                    (Vectors.dense(np.sqrt(row.vectors.dot(row.vectors))) *
                      Vectors.dense(np.sqrt(vecIn.dot(vecIn))))) 
            ).toArray().tolist()))

df.rdd.map(lambda row: cosSim(row, vecIn)).toDF(['CosSim']).show(truncate=False)
```

2. [`mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix) with [`columnSimilarities`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix.columnSimilarities):

```py
spark.createDataFrame(
    IndexedRowMatrix(df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row.vectors.toArray())))
    .toBlockMatrix()
    .transpose()
    .toIndexedRowMatrix()
    .columnSimilarities()
    .entries)

## then filter the results (not shown)
```

3. replace Word2Vec model `/data/` with my own, then load 'revised' model and use `.findSynonyms()`:

```py
df_words_vectors.schema
## StructType(List(StructField(word,StringType,true),StructField(vector,ArrayType(FloatType,true),true)))

df_words_vectors.write.parquet("exiting_Word2Vec_model/data/", mode='overwrite')

new_Word2Vec_model = Word2VecModel.load("exiting_Word2Vec_model")

## vecIn = vector of same dimensions as 'vector' column in DataFrame saved over Word2Vec model /data/
new_Word2Vec_model.findSynonyms(vecIn, 20).show()
```